# How do I make Adobe Acrobat Reader DC keep Windows 10 awake?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, adobe-acrobat

How do I make Adobe Acrobat Reader DC keep Windows 10 awake?

For example, I can do this with Google Chrome – there is an extension for that.

The only solution that comes to mind is keeping Google Chrome running while I use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, but I am not happy with that.

Googling doesn't help.

*Side question:* Is there a general way in Windows 10 of making a certain program keep Windows 10 awake while the program is running?

Comment: "Is there a general way in Windows 10 of making a certain program keep Windows 10 awake while the program is running?" - Yes;  Involves having the source code to the application though.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Comment: @Run5k, no, I have not.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you will find that the simple answer is *"no, that capability doesn't exist within Adobe Acrobat Reader DC."*  There are other viable options that are both rudimentary and effective, but they don't involve Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @Run5k what options are you talking about?

Comment: The ones we suggested:  either a built-in workaround like the looping Media Player video, or a third-party solution like Caffeine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that capability exists within Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.  As a result, you would need to utilize something else to keep the computer awake.

Aside from actually changing the Windows power scheme so that the operating system never goes to sleep, as a short-term solution you could simply open a short video within Windows Media Player, mute the volume, set it to repeat, and minimize it.

Comment: My keeping-Chrome-running solution is much simpler than yours.

Comment: That would certainly work, but running Media Player isn't exactly a complicated solution and it doesn't have a well-known history of utilizing an inordinately large amount of system memory the way that Chrome has in the past.

Answer (score 1):

How about downloading a tool like [Caffeiene](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html) and using a batch file that would go something along the lines of:

```
@echo off
start "path/to/adobe/reader.exe"
start "path/to/Caffeine.exe"
```

to start the reader. It might seem more complex, but you only need to do it once, and the rest will be done automatically.